# Why is there an option in my BIOS , that can permeantly disable Intel anti-theft?

Tags: laptop

Why is there an option in my BIOS , that can permeantly disable Intel anti-theft ?

Or why is that useful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel anti-theft is an option you can turn on and off just like any other option. You do want that as people not necessary use it (it's not free as far as I know so turning it on without service doesn't do anything really) so that's why it's optional. If you want to protect it from people changing it when they steal your computer simply put password on BIOS.

Comment: There are other reasons it may have a disable option for - compatibility with other hardware/software it may conflict with, not to mention any internet/bandwidth/power/processing overheads.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Computrace anti theft, yes it will permanently disable that feature and it cannot be turned back on. Other types of Anti Theft bios level solutions may be the same when it comes to using the "permanently disable" function. There is a reason they use the word "permanently"

> The Absolute Anti-Theft solution is presently Deactivated. Note that the Activate or Disable options will permanently Activate or Disable the feature and no further changes will be allowed.

[Source of Information](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/BIOS-option-to-quot-permanently-disable-quot-Computrace/td-p/104500)